# Why there is no context menu shown after call openContextMenu(...)?

Tags: android

I have written an application that when I click an option menu, it should show a context menu in the view. I have registered a view in the onCreate() method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mLatestIntent = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.details_gallery);
    DataManager.getInstance().registerImageUpdateListener(this);
    mGallery = (HomeScreenGallery)findViewById(R.id.details_gallery);
    mGallery.setSingleTapListener(this);
    mAdapter = new
           EventDetailsAdapter(this,DataManager.getInstance().getChannel().getItems());
    mGallery.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    **registerForContextMenu(mGallery);**
    setData();
}
```

I have called openContextMenu() in the onOptionsItemSelected() method and sent the registered view to it

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case Constants.OPTION_MENU_SHARE:
        **this.openContextMenu(mGallery);**
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But there is nothing shown when I click the option menu, why?

Comment: context menu is not the option menu! Context menu is for long press on the gallery item.

Comment: Is onCreateContextMenu() called?

Comment: Yes, I know Context menu is for long press, and I have written the program that it's show context menu after I long press,but, I want to when I press option menu, it also shows context menu, how can I achieve it?